# Does GWT has some default empty AsyncCallback implementation?

Tags: java, gwt, asynccallback

In my code I don't want to do anything within onSuccess() and onFailure() methods. Maybe there is some default class that implements AsyncCallback and does nothing?

Comment: That sounds like a bad Idea. I don't know your usecase, but ignoring the error and the returnvalue makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing useful in the [javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html) in **All Known Implementing Classes** section, so the answer is: **no**.

You could easily write you own `EmptyAsyncCallback` class and use throughout the entire project though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type Void for empty return on the async callback

```
AsyncCallback<Void> callBack = new AsyncCallback<Void>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public class AsyncDoNothingCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {

  @Override
  public void onFailure(final Throwable caught) {
    // Maybe some log here
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(final T result) {
    // Same here
  }

}
```

And maybe you can also use something like:

```
public static final AsyncDoNothingCallback DO_NOTHING = new AsyncDoNothingCallback();
```